# vue/compiler-sfc ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, vue-sfc

I'm using Nuxt 2 and I keep seeing MANY `[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.` errors while running npm run dev.

I changed all occurrences of `::v-deep { .. }` to `::v-deep(.class) { .. }` and also the tried the shorthand `:deep(.class) { .. }` and still those errors are showing up in terminal for over a million time while on `npm run dev`.

[image: Terminal V-deep errors]

I tried:

- Delete node_modules.
- Delete Package-lock.json.
- npm cache verify

But still same problem.

Does anyone knows a way that makes those errors go away? I don't want to downgrade my vue version, it's currently on `^2.6.12`.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the error? it may be from a package, not from your code.

Comment: Try to make a search on your whole project. Also, isn't the error giving you a path where it happens? Maybe try to also remove the `.nuxt` directory, that one is used for cache? Btw, where is your issue happening (VScode or your terminal)?

Comment: @technophyle @kissu Those errors are showing in the terminal while running `npm run dev`, maybe over a 100 warning about with the same error I mentioned in the question above without any details about it's root place or anything. I added a screenshot in the question

@kissu Just tried to delete `.nuxt` folder and same outcome happened.

Comment: Are you by any luck using SASS? There are some people with the same issue on project's issues. We should start looking there: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues?q=is%3Aissue+deprecated Also, not sure if it's an actual CSS issue or some package upgrade. Mind sharing your package.json? Maybe an incompatibility there.

Comment: It has been fixed for vue 2 https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.7.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed in Vue's v2.7.11 release: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2711-2022-10-11

With the following commit: [sfc: remove sfc scoped deep syntax deprecation warnings](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/2f335b2f9d09b962f40e38740826d444e4fff073)